# AudioKit AKTimePitch does not work for the recoded file example.m4a

Tags: audiokit

I am building up a APP on iOS by AudioKit(version 4.5.3), and I find out the AKTimePitch class does not work for me, here is my code(objective-c xcode 10):

```
(IBAction)startButton:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"burncalory" withExtension:@"m4a"];
    AKAudioFile *file = [[AKAudioFile alloc] initForReading:url error:nil];
    AKAudioPlayer *player = [[AKAudioPlayer alloc] initWithFile:file looping:NO lazyBuffering:YES error:nil completionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Finished!");
    }];

    AKTimePitch *akTimePitch = [[AKTimePitch alloc] init:player rate:2.0 pitch:1600 overlap:8];
    AudioKit.output = akTimePitch;
    [akTimePitch start];
    [AudioKit startAndReturnError:nil];
    [player playFrom:0.0];
}
```

I check out the playground(4.5.3), and the sample of "Time Stretching and Pitch Shifting" works well.

Is there something wrong in my code to use AKTimePitch or something wrong with my audio file `example.m4a`? By the way, this audio file can be loaded and play well by AKAudioPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I found that the parameter in the `init` method does not work, but after I add `akTimePitch.pitch=1600` before `[player playFrom:0.0]`, then the AKTimePitch effects works!! I don't know why the `AKTimePitch *akTimePitch = [[AKTimePitch alloc] init:player rate:2.0 pitch:1600 overlap:8];` just does not work...